# Oracle SQL merge tables side by side

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 select queries which i would like to merge side by side. The common column is **name**. I dont want to use **UNION ALL** solutions since my select queries might have many columns.

```
(select 'e1' name,1 columna  from dual) table_1
```

```
name  columna  
e1    1
```

```
(select 'h1' name,2 columnb  from dual) table_2
```

```
name    columnb    
h1      2
```

```
(select 't1' name,3 columnc  from dual) table_3
```

```
name    columnc
t1      3
```

The **output i am looking for** is:

```
name columna columnb columnc  
e1   1     
h1           2
t1                   3
```

I believe I need the full outer join. I tried left outer with (+) syntax.

```
select table_1.name,columna,columnb,columnc from  
(select 'e1' name,1 columna  from dual) table_1,  
(select 'h1' name,2 columnb  from dual) table_2,  
(select 't1' name,3 columnc  from dual) table_3  
where  
table_1.name=table_2.name(+)  
and table_1.name=table_3.name(+)
```

but the output is:

```
name columna columnb columnc
e1   1
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` perhaps?

Comment: (Unrelated) Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: no , column names are different. when  you use union  the column names will be same

Comment: Please, add dual table structure.

Comment: You can't write a full outer join with the `(+)` operator.

Comment: I  realized that. what is the best way to get the desired output without using union  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're after something like the following?:

```
with t1 as (select 'e1' name, 1 columna from dual),
     t2 as (select 'h1' name, 2 columnb, 2.5 columnc from dual),  
     t3 as (select 't1' name, 3 columnd from dual union all
            select 'h1' name, 4 columnd from dual)
select coalesce(t1.name, t2.name, t3.name) name,
       t1.columna,
       t2.columnb,
       t2.columnc,
       t3.columnd
from   t1
       full outer join t2 on t1.name = t2.name
       full outer join t3 on t1.name = t3.name or t2.name = t3.name
order by name;

NAME    COLUMNA    COLUMNB    COLUMNC    COLUMND
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
e1            1                       
h1                       2        2.5          4
t1                                             3
```

This uses full outer joins to join the tables together (note the use of the "OR" when joining the third table), and assumes the name column is unique in each table.

Comment: This looks  like what i need. Coalesce function makes it clearer. Is there anyway to write full outer join  with(+) sign?

Comment: There is, but it's way more complicated; why would you even bother? Use the ANSI syntax; it's easier to understand, maintain, and self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `union all`:

```
select 'e1' name, 1 columna, null columnb, null columnc from dual
union all
select 'h1', null, 2, null from dual
union all
select 't1', null, null, 3 from dual
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d0cdd86c7184a1d3c50575063ccd96e5)**:

```
NAME | COLUMNA | COLUMNB | COLUMNC
:--- | ------: | ------: | ------:
e1   |       1 |    null |    null
h1   |    null |       2 |    null
t1   |    null |    null |       3
```

Comment: @DudeSkywalk: see the fiddle that is part of my answer. This does produce the result that you asked for.

Comment: Yes, it works but Union all is  does not suit my needs.  You have to specifically  type all the columns and non matching values as null. The select queries  will have many columns. I dont want to write each of them one by one.

Comment: @Dude Skywalk: But that's the way to get the result you are after. You can of course write a computer program that just executes the separate queries and fills a grid as desired or write a program that writes the query for you.